# SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined en Slim Framework PHP

Tags: php, rest, login, slim

No encuentro porque me esta tirando este error.
Ya revise varias preguntas de stackoverflow y ninguna resolvió mi problema.

Mi parámetro **:contra** , lo necesito como un **string en mi query**, si no uso las comillas simples 'x', mi query no sale como lo necesito por el 'as varbinary'.

De hecho, si corro mi query tal cual lo corro en mi Management Studio, si me funciona bien, por lo cual esto me dice que mi problema esta en la parte que le paso los parámetros a mi query.

```
$app->post('/login3', function($request, $response){
    try{
        //instancia DB
        $db = new db();

        //conexion
        $db = $db -> getConnection();


        $sql = "SELECT * FROM Operador where CONTRASENA = CAST( ':contra' as varbinary) AND OPERADOR_CLAVE = :oper";

        $pre = $db->prepare($sql, array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_FWDONLY));

        if($sql){

            $values = array(
                ':oper' => $request->getParam('oper'),
                ':contra' => $request->getParam('contra')
            );

            $pre->execute($values);
            $result = $pre->fetch();

            if($result){
                return $response->withJson(array('status' => 'true','result'=>$result),200);
            }else{
                return $response->withJson(array('status' => 'Not Login'),422);
            }

        }else{
            return $response->withJson(array('status' => 'Username & Password Not Match'),422);
        }
    }catch(Exception $ex){
        return $response->withJson(array('error' => $ex->getMessage()),422);
    }
});
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

- A. Cedano :
  Es verdad lo que comentas, pero necesito que sea un String el que sea casteado a varbinary, si no lo hago asi, termina casteando un int como varbinary, por lo cual mi query no resulta como lo necesito. Adjunto imagen.
  [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No puedes poner comillas simples a los marcadores, prueba así: `SELECT * FROM Operador where CONTRASENA = CAST( :contra as varbinary) AND OPERADOR_CLAVE = :oper`. En tu código actual no reconoce el marcador, **lo interpreta como una cadena cualquiera**.

Comment: Totalmente cierto, lo se. Editare mi pregunta para aclarar ese punto.

Comment: Así debería funcionar. No entiendo el motivo de la conversión, ¿dices que lo necesitas como String? ¿De qué tipo es el dato? ¿Y si quieres un string, por qué lo casteas a `varbinary` y no a `varchar` por ejemplo? ¿? Y di también qué quieres decir con que *no sale como la necesito*  ... qué es lo que necesitas, qué es lo que sale?

Comment: Explica el lío que tienes con el  `CAST` porque no entiendo nada. Qué es lo que quieres convertir, de qué a qué y por qué y qué es lo que arroja. ¿No será que estás usando el tipo de dato equivocado?

Comment: No es lo mismo castear un String a varbinary a castear un int a varbinary, te tira diferente resultado. El casteo lo hago para que nadie mas que el usuario de su cuenta sepa la contraseña, nisiquera la base de datos guardara la contraseña real.

Comment: ¿De que otra manera puedo, de una manera sencilla, mantener seguro las contraseñas de los usuarios?

Comment: Yo sigo sin entender... Lo que tienes es un problema de interpretación de los tipos de datos o sobre el manejo de contraseñas, ¿por qué no haces un hash de la contraseña o algo así? [Lee por ejemplo](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4037/storing-passwords-in-a-secure-way-in-a-sql-server-database/) o bien [esto otro](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/encrypt-a-column-of-data?view=sql-server-2017), o algún artículo sobre asegurar contraseñas.

Comment: Tal vez sea así. Revisare esa parte, dejare abierta la pregunta por si recibo alguna otra respuesta. Gracias por aclararme.

Comment: De acuerdo, de todos modos, la respuesta a **esta** pregunta es esta: `SELECT * FROM Operador where CONTRASENA = CAST( :contra as varbinary) AND OPERADOR_CLAVE = :oper`, porque los marcadores jamás pueden ir ente comillas. Lo otro es un problema de SQL en sí, sobre tipos y protección de datos. Son dos problemas totalmente diferentes.